# Manga where a girl is reincarnated, becomes a maid for the king and queen, and discovers her one brother is God of Death

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

A while ago I read a manga and now I can't remember the name. It was about a girl who became like a mother for her brothers after their mom died. The whole family then dies in a fire and the girl is reincarnated in a world with magic, but because she was such a good caretaker for her family she becomes a maid for an old couple. She then finds out the old couple are the old king and queen, then they move back to the palace and she then becomes a maid for the new king.

Later in the story she meets a man called god of death (or something similar) who turns out to be her brother. Even later in the story she finds her other brother who also reincarnated as a great sage.

Comment: Welcome Owen. Please check-out our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add some details such as when it was written, any artwork you remember etc..

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the girl's hair?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*I Was Reborn as a Housekeeper in a Parallel World!*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-was-reborn-as-a-housekeeper-in-a-parallel-world)

> Erena, a high school girl, died in a fire... but she was reborn in a
> parallel world! She now works as a housekeeper for a wealthy elderly
> couple, using the housekeeping skills she honed in her men-only
> family. One day, the elderly couple move in with their son, but his
> house is the royal castle! The couple were actually the retired
> previous King and Queen, and their son is the King! Can Erena's
> housekeeping skills help pave a new way for the kingdom?!
>
> [image: Cover: purple haired man and black haired maid]

---

[image: Comic panels: AH...I REALIZED PEOPLE CAN DIE REALLY EASILY. ONE NIGHT I WOKE UP AND I WAS SURROUNDED BY A SEA OF FIRE. I DON'T NEED TO WORRY ABOUT GETTING MARRIED ANYMORE.]